# Улучшенный Partial<T>

Tags: массивы, typescript, typescript-типы

Можно ли сделать тип с такой сигнатурой:

```
type Optional<T> = ...
```

…который мог бы преобразовать это:

```
type A = {
    a: number
    b: string[]
}
```

…в это:

```
type Optional_A = {
    a?: number | null
    b?: (string | null | undefined)[] | null
}
```

С преобразованием св-ва `a` нет никаких проблем:

```
type BadOptional<T> = { [K in T]?: K | null }
```

Основная проблема с массивом. Если бы TypeScript поддерживал нечто подобное:

```
type ImpossibleOptional<T> = {
    [K in T]?: (K extends U[]
        ? (U | null | undefined)[]
        : K) | null
}
```

…то решение нашлось бы само собой, но нет.

Comment: Так он же поддерживает... Сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKA7ArgLYBGEATmlMTgM7BkCWuA5gNoC6KAviiqJFACyIAPJhgAUQAeAHgAqAPgTJKrANYQQUJlA0gA9gDMoc9gH4cc9ZvZQIU4BFwATGlAAUTQ+SgBVAJQcUGYevlAAPnj4ADbREVD4LhCGTBDOgbaRBLFQltYgmVGxANzcvPzQYsBwiMJV0jIwCihAA)

```
type A = {
  a: number
  b: string[]
}

type MyOptEx<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: T[key] extends (infer U)[] ? (U | null | undefined)[] | null : T[key] | null;
}

type OptA = MyOptEx<A>
```

Получается:

```
type OptA = {
    a?: number | null | undefined;
    b?: (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined;
}
```

Хотя вообще-то, возможно стоит прописывать явно и `undefined` для значения - вдруг когда-то typescript передумает и перестанет его сам добавлять. Хотя, вероятно, это уж слишком breaking change для них, но постепенно туда движутся. Может быть очередным strict-флагом добавят.

Оказывается, такой флаг уже есть: [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes).

Comment: так во-от зачем этот `infer` нужен. "Within the extends clause of a conditional type, it is now possible to have infer declarations that introduce a type variable to be inferred." звучит гораздо непонятнее, чем это

Comment: @return, очень полезная штука, на самом деле)

Comment: а только щас заметил, у вас если не массив, возвращается `T | null`, а должно `T[key] | null`

Comment: @return, да, поправил.

Comment: @return, а флаг-то уже есть)

Comment: не знал о его существовании (в прочем, ничего нового), спасибо за находку